# Format a timestamp into text

Tags: c, linux, unix, sed, awk

I want to get the Modify date of a file and then format it into a human readable date. I am running a C program that gets information on when a particular file was last modified.
My C Code contains a sytem cmd which contains a number of egreps, awks, seds separated by pipes.  Using sed or awk or something similar, how can I convert 06 to June (This can be any month so an array or something is required) What I am trying to achieve is to end up with a string similar to:

My C code contains:

```
    char string1[100] = "";
    #define MAXCHAR 100
    FILE *fp;
    char str[MAXCHAR], str2[MAXCHAR];
    char* filename = "newfile";

    /*
    stat: run 'stat' on the dtlName file to display status information.
    egrep: search for the pattern 'Modify' and print the lines containing it.
    awk: Get columns 2 & 3
    sed: replace the . with a space, leaving 3 columns of output
    awk: only print cols 1 & 2 to newfile
    sed: replace '-' with ' ' in newfile
    awk: format output in newfile
    */
    sprintf(string1, "/bin/stat %s  \
                    | egrep Modify \
                    | /bin/awk '{print $2, $3}' \
                    | /bin/sed 's/\\./ /g' \
                    | /bin/awk '{print $1, $2}' \
                    | /bin/sed 's/-/ /g' \
                    | /bin/awk '{print $3,$2\", \"$1,\"at\",$4}' > newfile"
                    , dtlName);
    system(string1);
    fp = fopen(filename, "r");
    while (fgets(str, MAXCHAR, fp) != NULL)
            sprintf(str2,"%s", str);

    /*  Write information to file */
    DisplayReportFile (report);
    ReportEntry (report,L"Source file: %s, Created: %s\n\n",dtlName,str2);
```

Comment: shouldn't it be 'sprintf(str, "... > %s", ..., filename);'?

Comment: That's sort of impressive, really.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is the working version of the same program:

```
#include <sys/types.h>
#include <sys/stat.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <time.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int main(int argc, char ** argv)
{
        if (argc < 2) exit(1);

        char *filename = argv[1];

        struct stat st;
        char s[1000];
        if (stat(filename, &st))
                exit(2);

        struct tm *mdtime = localtime( &st.st_mtime );
        strftime(s, sizeof(s), "%D", mdtime);

        printf("%s\n", s);
}
```

See [strftime](http://linux.die.net/man/3/strftime) for more formats.

Answer (score 1):

normally you would use fstat() and strftime().

Answer (score 1):

Why not use

```
 #include <fcntl.h>
 #include <sys/types.h>
 #include <sys/stat.h>

 int stat(const char *restrict path, struct stat *restrict buf);
```

(from `man -s2 stat`)

this will give you a time_t with the time of last modification

then you can use `ctime_r` or `asctime_r` or `mktime` to get the appropriate information out.

Answer (score 0):

Is the awk sed combination necessary? Why not just call fstat on the file and extract the modify date from there? You can then convert this to a string with a call to ctime().

Answer (score 0):

I do not know if it is useful.But once I did something like that.
While getting that string just process that string and get `Month` after that you can use

```
if(strcmp(May,string1)==0)
return 5;
```

you can get your desired output.